# relationship doesn't work in nhibernate

Tags: c#, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am using fluent NHibernate. Mapping is done in vb class. My mapping code for friend table(class) is

```
Map(Function(x) x.FriendID)

References(Function(x) x.UserID_friendID).Column("FriendID")
```

When these both lines in code then dehydrate error occur. If i remove references row then values inserted in table correctly. But then relationship doesn't work. If remove map(function **) row then relationship works, but at time of insert FriendID column in friends table remains null. Please guide what i am missing or doing wrong to achieve both relationship and also save friendid in friend table. I also tried .inverse() but same result.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain in C# *(Suprisingly not as easy to read VB than I expected...)*. From the mapping above I guess that your Entity looks like this:

```
Friend Friend   { get; set; } // the property UserID_friendID
int    FriendID { get; set; }
```

Which is ok for NHibernate, but it for sure means, that both properties do target the same column `"FirendID"`. For reading we do not have any issue, both values could be populated, but for writing we can pass *(to DB)* only **one** value *(one column)*. The mapping *(in C#)* would be like this:

```
References(x => x.Friend).Column("FriendID")
Map(x => x.FriendID)
  .Not.Insert()
  .Not.Update()
```

Now NHibernate will be properly working when INSERT or UPDATE, and also provide both values for SELECT.

*NOTE: During creation, with the above mapping, we have to assign the `Reference` **Friend**, because this value is handled by write operations. Assing value type FriendID is not engough...*